# SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL not forwarded with Internet Explorer

Tags: apache, certificate, client-certificates

We've been using Apache for ages together withClient Certificates to login users. Recently we have added a new server based on nginx.

Logging in with Chrome and certs works fine on both.
Logging in with IE or Edge on at least Windows 7 and 10 and Apache works fine.
Logging in with the IE or Edge on nginx does not work. It does request the client cert though.

So far I have found that SSL_CLIENT_M_SERIAL is non existent when logging in with IE + nginx. It is however set with Chrome or IE+Apache.

I'm checking this with PHP: var_dump($_SERVER);

Anyone ever encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so my colleague fixed it by adding this to the server{} directive:

```
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!ADH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:!kEDH;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

No clue which one of these did the trick. But it works in IE now.